# Python: Removing OUT-OF-ORDER numbers from the list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning python right now, but I can't seem to work out how to remove elements from a array, that is not in order.

Say, I have

```
np.array([1.3,2.2,2.3,4.2,5.1,3.2,5.3,2.1,1.1,5.2,3.1])
```

I need to remove 1.3 and 1.1, because 1.2 is missing. Also 4.2 needs to be removed, because I don't have 4.1 and 4.3. In short I want to remove **`OUT-OF-ORDER`** numbers from the list.

How do I do that?

These three are correct: 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3

it is for this assignment:

> You are working on a data set from a series of experiments, each of
>   which consists of three parts. The experiments have been performed in
>   a randomized order. Each experiment has been assigned an
>   experiment-number and a part-number, which are joined into one decimal
>   number called an id-number. The id-number is formed by separating the
>   experiment-number and part-number by a decimal point. For example, the
>   experiment number 17 part 3 has been assigned the id-number 17.3.
>   Note, that you can compute the experiment-number from the id-number by
>   rounding down to the nearest integer. 
>   You notice that due to errors,
>   for some of the experiments all three parts have not been completed.
>   For further analysis, you need to exclude all experiments where one or
>   more parts are not available. You can safely assume that if there are
>   3 id-numbers with the same experiment-number, the experiment is
>   complete.
>
> ** Problem definition **
>   Create a function that takes as an input
>   a vector of id-numbers and returns a vector of id-numbers where all
>   incomplete experiments have been removed. The id-numbers that are not
>   removed must remain in the same order as in the original vector.

*Solution Template*

```
def removeincomplete(id):
#your code here
 return completeid
```

Comment: What have you tried? Would you mind posting some more sample input and output? Should it just check \*.1, \*.2, and \*.3 for each number, or is there more to it? If for example 3.1 is missing, should it remove all the 3.\*'s or only 3.2 because that's the only number adjacent to it?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, but I can post the assignment in the post

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make much sense at the moment. Try to state more clearly what you need to do..

Comment: The assignment is pretty explicit what to do: For each element in the list, use `round` to remove the decimal part, then see if the three .1, .2, .3 experiments are in the list. If so, keep it, otherwise not.

Comment: try to break the problem up in to smaller bits. e.g.: take the first number - how can your function determine if it needs to be removed? (hint: look for other numbers with the same experiment) How then to tell if another number is from the same experiment? (hint: what happens if you do `int(n)` or `round(n)` as @tobias_k suggests). Then try your code, and think about why it doesn't work yet (it's pretty rare, even for professional coders, to get it right first time!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [3]: from operator import itemgetter
In [4]: from itertools import groupby  
In [5]: lst
Out[5]: [1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1]

#getting the index of all the floats
In [6]: idx=[(i,j) for (i,j) in enumerate(lst)]

#Converting floats to strings
In [7]: str_lst=[str(i) for i in lst]

#Using groupby from itertools to group the elemnets
In [8]: a=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(str_lst),key=itemgetter(0))]

In [9]: b=[float(x) for _list in a if len(_list)==3 for x in _list ]

In [10]:  [j for i,j in idx if j in b]
Out[10]: [2.2, 2.3, 5.1, 5.3, 2.1, 5.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

as your problem has a definite set of values you can use this logic:

1. sort your array and store it temp array.

2. now start traversing this sorted array and check the difference like, you can use this kind of approach

```
if(array[1] - array[0] == 0.1) && (array[2] - array[1] == 0.1))
 move to array[3]
else
 add array[0] to del_list
```

follow this until you reach last element, take care of boundary conditions.

3.now traverse through this del_list and delete elements from your original array, you can use this logic for this:

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 a.remove(2) # 2 is not the position!
 print a
 [1, 3, 4]
```